On probability of unordered sample being ordered and more
Here are two introductory exercises on order statistics in An Intermediate Course in Probability by Gut.

Exercise 1.1-1.2 Let $X_{(k)}$ or $X_{k;n}$ denote the $k$th order variable of a sample of size $n$, where $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is the sample from a distribution with distribution function $F$. Suppose that $F$ is continuous.
(a) Compute $P(X_k=X_{(k)},k=1,2,\ldots,n)$, that is, the probability that the original, unordered sample is in fact (already) ordered.
(b) Suppose we make one further observation. Compute $P(X_{k;n}=X_{k;n+1})$, that is, the probability that the $k$th smallest observation still is the $k$th smallest observation.

It's not assumed anywhere that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent, but I don't think it matters. First, I think we can rule out for there to be any $X_i=X_j$ for $i\neq j$, since $P(X_i=X_j)=0$. The way I'd argue is that $$P((X_i,X_j) \in A) = \int_A f(x,y)\ dxdy,$$i.e. $P(X_i=X_j) = \int_{y=x}f(x,y)\, dxdy$. But the set $A=\{(x,y):y=x\}$ is of Lebesgue measure $0$ in $\mathbb R^2$, so $P(X_i=X_j)=0$. Thus the observations are distinct.
My solution to (a) is simply $1/n!$, since we've got $n!$ possible orderings, and one of the orderings is the ordered one, so $1/n!$.
For (b), I'm not sure what the author has in mind. I feel confident about computing various probabilities, but I don't think I understand which probability $P(X_{k;n}=X_{k;n+1})$ is. Grateful for any help.

"...is the sample from distribution $F$..." implicitly means they are independent I believe

Yeah, I believe they are independent as well. The author prior to this exercise talks about random samples, so...


We do need independence. Otherwise $P(X_1=X_2)$ could be $1$. I think the word "sample" usually means a "random sample". So the author has assumed independence.
I agree with $\frac{1}{n!}$ for the first question.
I think the 2nd question is asking $P(X_{n+1} > X_{k;n})$. Since $X_{n+1}$ and  $X_{k;n}$ are independent (the latter only depends on $X_1,\dots,X_n$), this is the expected CDF of $X_{k;n}$, i.e., $$
\sum_{i=k}^n \binom{n}{i} \mathbb{E}\left\lbrace \left[F(X)\right]^i \left[1-F(X)\right]^{n-i}\right\rbrace.$$

Graphically,
$$X_{0;n}:=-\infty<\underbrace{X_{1;n}<X_{2;n}<\cdots<X_{k-1;n}<X_{k;n}}_{k\text{ observations}}\underbrace{<X_{k+1;n}<\cdots<X_{n;n}<\infty}_{\text{insert }X_{n+1}\text{ into this part}}=:X_{n+1;n}.$$
If $X_{n+1}$ lies between $X_{a;n}$ and $X_{a+1;n}$, order statistics up to the $a$th will not change, but order statistics starting from the $(a+1)$st will shift to the right by one place.

EDIT: As @psie points out, this probability is simply $\frac{n-k+1}{n+1}$ as there are $n-k+1$ equally like slots out of $n+1$ for $X_{n+1}$ to be inserted in, without affecting the location of $X_{k;n}$. Evaluating the expected CDF through integration-by-parts and induction will result in the same result, but being laborious.

Thank you for the answer! Is it possible to describe in words what the probability $P(X_{n+1} > X_{k;n})$ is? I guess it is a bit unclear what the author means in part (b), but at least I would have thought we would be interested in $P(X_{n+1} > X_{n;n})$. I am unsure myself.

@psie Once we sort the $n$  observations, the wanted event is the same the next observation $X_{n+1}$ larger than the $k$th smallest observation $X_{k;n}$, so that $X_{k;n}$ remains at the same location even if one more observation is added. Just added a graphical presentation at the end.

Thanks, this clarified it. I think your interpretation of the problem is correct. Wouldn't the probability of inserting $X_{n+1}$ into the part you have underbraced be $\frac{n-k+1}{n+1}$, i.e. there are $n+1$ slots in total for $X_{n+1}$ to be inserted in, and above $X_{k;n}$ there are $n-k+1$ slots: $$\underbrace{\phantom{\quad}}{\text{1st slot}}X{1;n}\underbrace{\phantom{\quad}}{\text{2nd slot}}X{2;n}\quad\ldots\quad X_{n;n}\underbrace{ \ }_{(n+1)\text{st slot}}.$$

@psie Good point!

Here:
$$X_{k;n}=X_{k;n+1}\iff X_{n+1}\in\{X_{k+1;n+1},\dots,X_{n+1;n+1}\}$$
so that:
$$P(X_{k;n}=X_{k;n+1})=\sum_{i=k}^nP(X_{n+1}=X_{i+1;n+1})$$
By symmetry the terms on RHS all take value $\frac1{n+1}$.
So we end up with:
$$P(X_{k;n}=X_{k;n+1})=\frac{n+1-k}{n+1}=1-\frac{k}{n+1}$$

I think for (b) they mean, given that the sample of size $n$ has a certain order, with $X_{(1)}=X_{k_1},\ldots,X_{(n)}=X_{k_n}$, where $(k_i)_{i=1}^n$ is a permutation of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, what is the probability that the first $n$ sample points will be ordered in the same way when making one further observation? We have $$X_{k_1}\phantom{\quad} X_{k_2}\phantom{\quad}\ldots\phantom{\quad}X_{k_n},$$and $X_{n+1}$ can be either greater than $X_{k_n}$, between $X_{k_n}$ and $X_{k_{n-1}}$, and so on. There are $n+1$ possibilities and the probability that $X_{n+1}>X_{k_n}$ is $1/(n+1)$.

I think this interpretation of the question is not correct, although the answer to the interpretation is. I leave it here for the curious reader.
